# JavaScript, can't draw paddles and ball in pong. Can somebody please explain me why?

Tags: javascript, canvas, pong

Can somebody explain me why this code doesn't work? It's supposed to draw two paddles and a ball (rectangular) in a canvas so far.  I'm new in JavaScript, and I'm following this YouTube tutorial, but I got stuck almost at the very beginning. Besides not knowing why it doesn't draw all the elements of the game I also don't understand the meaning of the var = loop function inside the main function. Help please!!

```js
    var WIDTH=700;
    var HEIGHT=500;
    var pi=Math.PI;

    var canvas;
    var ctx;
    var keystate;

    var player;
    var ai;
    var ball;

    player = {
        x: null,
        y: null,
        width: 20,
        height: 100,

        update: function(){},
        draw: function (){
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
            }
    }

    ai = {
        x: null,
        y: null,
        width: 20,
        height: 100,

        update: function(){},
        draw: function (){
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
            }
    }


    ball = {
        x: null,
        y: null,
        side: 20,

        update: function(){},
        draw: function (){
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.side, this.side);
            }
    }


    function main(){
        canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = WIDTH;
        canvas.height = HEIGHT;
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);

        init();

        var loop = function(){
            update();
            draw();

            window.requestAnimationFrame(loop,canvas);
        };
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop,canvas);
    }

    function init(){
        player.x = player.width;
        player.y = (HEIGHT - player.height)/2;

        ai.x = WIDTH - (player.width + ai.width);
        ai.y = (HEIGHT - ai.height)/2;

        ball.x = (HEIGHT - ball.side)/2;
        ball.y = (HEIGHT - ball.side)/2;
    }

    function update(){
        ball.update();
        player.update();
        ai.update();
    }

    function draw(){
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";

        ball.draw();
        player.draw();
        ai.draw();
    }

    main();

</script>
```

Comment: Not sure if you care, but there is an error on line 61, the error being when you append `canvas` to the body. The error says you cannot append Child of null. May i suggest doing the following:          `body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]; body.appendChild(canvas);` Please be sure to tell me if that helped at all or if you think its irrelevant, because hopefully at least one person learns from this.

Comment: I did both of the things that you guys suggested, plus I rewrote the script in the body section instead of the head section and it worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You are drawing everything in white.
That's why you see nothing. The background is white and the shapes you draw are as well.

Try

```
function draw(){
    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);

    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000"
    ball.draw();
    player.draw();
    ai.draw();
    ctx.restore();
}
```